# Count 3 types of delimiters (comma, semicolon, pipe) from different files

Tags: sed

I am trying to develop the similar thing. But my requirement is little bit different. I would like to count the number of delimiters in the 1st row and the 2nd row. If delimiters from both the rows are matching then fine otherwise the file need to be moved to the reject folder. Below is the script. But here I have a question, how do I count for 3 different delimiters in different files. For example I have comma, semicolon and pipe delimiters. In the below script in `sed` command how to check for 3 types of delimiters at the same time?

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox

findresult=$(find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" ))

Count=sed -n 1p $findresult | tr ',' '\n' | wc -l
Count2=sed -n 2p $findresult | tr ',' '\n' | wc -l

echo $Count echo $Count2

if [ $Count != $Count2 ]
then echo "Mis Match"
  mv $findresult /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/reject
else echo "Match"
  exit
fi
```

Comment: I've tried to reformat your code so it looks like code. Please check that I haven't altered the meaning.

Comment: Thank you Dave, I am new to the stackoverflow

Comment: No problem. If you're planning to hang around, it'll be well worth teaching yourself how [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown) works.

Comment: Just now I learned to do it by giving 4 times space :) Thanks Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the delimiters are otherwise parts of the two first lines, you could use this generic GNU awk script:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN  { FS="[,;|]" }            # Set Field Separators
FNR==1 { count = NF }            # Remember Number of Fields from the first line
FNR==2 { 
  if(count != NF)                # If second line has the same number of fields
    print "Mismatch: " FILENAME  # Report the mismatched file
  nextfile                       # Skip to next input file
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f parse.awk infile1 infile2 ...
```

This will output any files with a count mismatch.

Comment: Hi Thor, thank you. Could you please explain your code. I dont understand wht next file does.

Comment: @KiranChapidi: See inline comments

Comment: I have multiple file about 50 file, randomly arrives in the system. The files might contain any of the three delimiters (comma or semicolon or pipe). if the 1st line inside the file delimiters count doesn't match with the count of delimiters in the 2nd line the file need to be moved to the reject folder.

Comment: @KiranChapidi: Integrate the script in your process, e.g.: `find ... -exec awk -f parse.awk {} + | xargs mv -t /path/to/reject`. Note you need to remove the `"Mismatch: "` bit from the print statement

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a file, containing just commas, semi-colons and pipe characters:

```
echo ",,,;;;;|||||" >test.txt
```

Then I ran following command:

```
echo $(($(grep -o "," test.txt | wc -l) + $(grep -o ";" test.txt | wc -l) + $(grep -o "|" test.txt | wc -l)))
```

The result was 12, as expected.

Comment: This counts delimiters in the whole file, not just the first two lines

Comment: `cat test.txt | head -2 | grep -o "," | wc -l`, so you only count the first two lines.

Comment: OP wants to compare the count of the first line with the count of the second.

Answer (score 0):

I found something below to include all the delimiters at the same time. Please check if that is correct.

```
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox

findresult=$(find $pathname -type f ( -name "messagemulti.csv" -or -name "messagesemi.txt" -or -name "comma2.txt" -or -name "messagepipe.txt" -or -name "tokkalodi.txt" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv" -or -name "DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv" -or -name "ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" -or -name "ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv" ))

Count=sed -n 1p $findresult | tr '[,;|]' '\n' | wc -l
Count2=sed -n 2p $findresult | tr '[,;|]' '\n' | wc -l

echo $Count echo $Count2

if [ $Count != $Count2 ]
then echo "Mis Match"
mv $findresult /opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/reject
else echo "Match"
exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the delimiters by moviing them to a new line, replace by ';', and count them:

```
sed '2 s/[|,;]/\n;/g' ${findresult} | grep -c ';'
```

When you only want to know which have the same number, you do not need to count them.
Delete all other characters and replace any remaining character with a dot.

```
if [[ $(sed '1s/[^|,;]//g;s/././g' ${findresult}) != 
      $(sed '2s/[^|,;]//g;s/././g' ${findresult}) ]]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

on bash shell type

```
i=
pathname=/opt/interfaces/sample_check/mvfiles/inbox
for file in messagemulti.csv messagesemi.txt comma2.txt messagepipe.txt tokkalodi.txt ADMC_POSITION-LT3213.csv DMC_CASHFLOW248.csv ADMC_EQBASKET-WEIGHTS_52387.csv ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv ADMC_POSITION-DDD7.csv
{
while read -r l ;do s=${l//[!,;\|]}; c=${#s}; ((++i==1))&&d=$c; if((i==2));then ((d==c)) ||mv -v $file $pathname/$file ;fi ;done<$file
}
```